# 70s/80s comic space ship like dome/ball/asteroid on its journey through space

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

I saw this comic book in a shop in the mid 80s. The book could have been older though.
Don't remember the title or publisher.

It was about the journey of a bunch of astronauts/scientists/kids on this space ship that was more like a moon or large ball satellite with its own atmosphere under a dome/shield and houses and structures on the surface of the ship/moon/satellite.

I don't remember the name of the ship but something like "Moon 2" or something similar seems to ring familiar.

It seemed to be the first issue of the series and it was about them all getting "on board" and taking off (= flying away from earth's orbit)

There was some mystery plot in there somewhere. don't remember what about.
The story ended with some cliff-hanger so I assume there were more issues.

Not sure if that rings any bells for anyone.

Comment: Was it an American or European comic?

Comment: I actually don't know. The shop I saw it in was in Germany, so it may very have been European. 
I was in my early teens back then and I hope I'm not mixing up different stories.
If I remember correctly it was a larger format than the normal DC size comics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you saw it in a German store, it might have been [Sigma Gigantic](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigantik) (a.k.a Gigantik), which was created as a series for the German [Zack](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zack_(Zeitschrift)) magazine started in 1979 by the now defunct publishing company [Koralle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koralle-Verlag) and was later reissued as a standalone. Artwork was by [José Cardona](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Cardona_(Comiczeichner)) and [Víctor Mora](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADctor_Mora_(Comicautor)).

The titular "Gigantik" was an Asteroid that kept an atmosphere under a transparent shield and was orbited by a set of smaller defense satellites. Main characters were "Ronald Ranger" and his girlfriend Mireia, accompanied by the odd couple of Piccolo and Goliath (the latter a rather dumb combat robot, the former his smaller and smarter companion).

[A Google image search will bring up the covers where you can see the glas dome](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigma%20gigantic&rlz=1C5GCEA_enDE849DE849&sxsrf=AJOqlzWip47rMkTIj3dd1uzdnUwlwtG6Pw:1676290843459&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAy46CvpL9AhXCSvEDHeA9Ax0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=693&dpr=2).

Since this was created for the German market, and was never published outside continental Europe, all references are in German.

Comment: O.M.G! This is it. 
How did you find that? I had almost given up on ever finding out.
Thank you very much

Comment: This shows that it is important to make a note of which language you have seen or a read a thing in.  :-)

Comment: @freiversuch "how did you find that" - I looked in my bookshelf. I loved that comic as a kid, and a while back bought the whole set on eBay (Koralle had partnered with publishers in other European countries, and they issued a few more Volumes after koralle folded which were then translated to German).  However I had forgotten that this was written for children and teenagers in the 1970s, and does not necessarily meet the taste of an adult in the 2020s. If i were you, I would leave it at the happy memory.